# It's possible hackers have access a home directory by http?

Tags: linux

I would like to know, that if it possible hackers have access a home directory, with apache?

If it is, how i can protect-me from this?

Answer (score 3):

It's how you configure your apache2 .

The only way the hacker can breach your directory is via open port or unprotected sites .
They can sniff the transaction packet to your server . With those information via sites, they can just attack your database or bring down your site.

The only way they can access your home is by :

- BruteForcing your root password
- Shell script via vulnerability.

It's best to do a vulnerability test to ensure there's no loophole.